# Netstat do not show my ip

Tags: networking

On my local network, my nas (synology 5.2) has this ip: `192.168.1.13`.

My ip adress on internet is like `90.30.*.*`.

But when I use `netstat` on my nas for information about my current connections I've got this:

```
> netstat -tp 
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 demeter.home:2222       hestia.home:59607       ESTABLISHED 31390/1
tcp        0      0 169.254.117.34:6690     rev-18-253-20.isp3.alsatis.net:21086 ESTABLISHED 10978/syncd
tcp        0      0 demeter.home:6690       hestia.home:53183       ESTABLISHED 10978/syncd
[...]
```

Why my local address is with an ip that is not mine ?

BTW the ifconfig give me this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:32:BL:AB:LA  
          inet addr:192.168.1.13  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::211:<blabla> Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          [...]

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          [...]

tun1000   Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:169.254.117.34  P-t-P:169.254.117.33  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: 2001:db8:f::1147/64 Scope:Global
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1400  Metric:1
          RX packets:12599 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14934 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:2246761 (2.1 MiB)  TX bytes:5831393 (5.5 MiB)
```

Comment: do netstat -an. The 169.254 is also a local IP address.

Answer (score 1):

The 169.254.117.34 address is likely a link-local address registered by the **avahi** daemon.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking